# Translating obj-c code into swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need help on translating this obj-c code to swift. I am not sure how I should write a block...

```
    self.circularTimerView.frameBlock = ^(CircularTimerView *circularTimerView){
        circularTimerView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [circularTimerView intervalLength]];
    };
```

Thank you so much :)

Comment: Update your question with your Swift code so people can help. Explain what problem you are having with your Swift code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a closure instead of a block:

```
circularTimerView.frameBlock = { [unowned self] (circularTimerView:CircularTimerView) in
    circularTimerView.text = NSString(format:"%f",circularTimerView.intervalLength())
}
```

Comment: This seems like not working correctly. The error says "Expected ',' separator" and suggest ',' after unowned which does not seem correct.

Comment: The frameBlock type is "(CircularTimerView) -> ()" ?

Comment: I do not see the block type in both header and implementation file. Here is the library I'm trying to implement. https://github.com/lukescott/CircularTimerView

Comment: Well, the block/closure param is of CircularTimerView, so it should be fine.

Comment: never mind. I put an exclaimation mark after CircularTimerView and it worked. Thank you so much for helping me out :)

Comment: As Kahsn says, the `circularTimerView` parameter is (because this hasn't been audited for nullability) and implicitly unwrapped optional. Add the `!` in that parameter of the closure, e.g. `frameBlock = { (circularTimerView:CircularTimerView!) in ... }`.

Comment: Yes, if the library was not updated and added nullability the default type is unwrapped optional. Another option is to just remove the type and use `[unowned self] circularTimerView in` because type will be inferred.